# Hadoop splitting image into tiles for a segmentation process

Tags: image-processing, hadoop, split, tiff

I want to use Hadoop to process segmentation on large scale images (Pleiades image tif format)

The idea is to split the image into tiles and distribute them to each node.

The map task will be the segmentation process. I developped the segmentation algorithm using the OTB library written in C++.

I created an otb application which can be launched since a java program by giving the path of the tile and it returned the segmented tile.

I really don't know how to implement the split mechanism, I have to custom the fileInputFormat class and the RecorReader class but with what types of input keys and input values.

Actually I have to get the path to the tile to segment...

If someone has a suggestion ?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Solution strategy may depend on amount of images and variety of their sizes.
If you have a lot of images (much more then amount of free mapper slots in your cluster) you probably may consider process each image inside of mapper with StreamInputFormat and use your segmentation algorithm. Otherwise you may need to implement your own InputFormat that will form correct InputSplits.